# Selecting all sheet except the first in r and then bind it

Tags: r, spreadsheet, rbind

I have multiple excel file each containing different number of sheet. I want to merge all the sheet of all files except the 1st sheet of each file into a new data frame.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide a minimum reproducible example? Check out this post for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use rbind the columns must have the same name. Ignoring the 1st sheet should be done when calling the frame [-1], a little bit more information would help.

Comment: The columns have same name but i am unable to select all the sheets except sheet 1 of each excel file

Comment: library(xlsReadWrite) 
sheets <- c("Sheet 1","Sheet 2", etc...)

df <- data.frame()

for (x in 1:400) 
df <- rbind(df, read.xls("filename.xls", sheet=sheets[x]))
}


then you can just do df <- df[-1] and get rid of the first sheet